# Developing an Application using C++ or Java For GPS Receivers

Tags: gps

I have an idea for developing an app to be installed in a GPS receiver,this app should be able to communicate with a server.The connection could either be established through a cell phone network or internet or any suggestions.

Is this possible?

Can anyone help with suggestions?
Whats the best programming language would be more appropriate?
Any GPS devices that has this capability?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to do this, you can have a look at gpsd.

basically just com port communication and change NMEA formats, and send your info back to your server over the net.

I did my one with ruby under linux without addition library other than native.

For your question:
I would say any language you are comfortable will do. OS is not important, even on a ARM linux it should be okay.

Most gps should work, as long as they are NMEA formats. for more info you can have a look at http://gpsd.berlios.de/hardware.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.Did you have your app installed in the gps? which model? Do you mind outlining the procedure for me.Im new to embedded devices,so i need step by step.Thanks

Comment: i had a usb gps receiver, which collects gps parameter, i couldnt remember the model number. and a linux program that does com port communication which collects info from the gps.